# Are threads started simultaneously or there's delay between them?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

For example, there's a code:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    exec.execute(new SomeRunnable());
```

The statement `for` performs 1000000 operations of starting a thread and running its task.

We suggest that these threads are started simultaneously. Well, OK, but how are threads started at the same time if a statement `for` performs their operations consistenly, step-by-step: the first one, the second one, the third one, and so on?

```
for(int i=1; i<11; i++) {
    System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
}

// Actions are happened step-by-step, not simultaneosly
/* The output is:
Count is: 1
Count is: 2
Count is: 3
Count is: 4
Count is: 5
and so on */
```

Comment: What makes you think they do? Why do you think the compiler has any relevance to how threads are started at runtime? Read the javadoc of Executors.newCachedThreadPool().

Comment: newCachedPool was a typo, sorry.

Comment: It should be easy to provide more data on your confusion, what threads happen to soon after each other, what is the output you get when you add print statements vs. what you would expect?

Comment: I just can't imagine the common concept. How are tasks executed simultaneously if they don't have the same start time?

Comment: @luckystrrrike you start making water boil. Then you start defreezing some meat. Then you start watching the news. All these tasks don't start at the same time. But once they're started, they all execute concurrently: the water heats while the meat is defreezing while you watch the news. Isn't that quite natural?

Comment: In each of those `Runnable`, do `System.out.println('Started Thread: " + Counter"); System.out.flush();` at the start of the Runnable. Or the cheap way is to use `System.err.println` which will immediately write to the console and it will be in order of which Runnable's were executed first. ThreadPools usually use a queue to determine which tasks execute first (First In, First Out -- FIFO).. so it should actually be executed in order.

Comment: java Thread is some abstraction over low level thread, OS, and over multicore (mostly today) CPU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The threads are *started* one after the other (very, very quickly). If they're doing anything of any significance, they'll run in parallel.

From [the documentation of `Executors.newCachedThreadPool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool--):

> Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but will reuse previously constructed threads when they are available. These pools will typically improve the performance of programs that execute many short-lived asynchronous tasks. Calls to execute will reuse previously constructed threads if available. If no existing thread is available, a new thread will be created and added to the pool.

So your loop requests the execution of 10 `SomeRunnable` runnables. The pool will create threads as necessary to accommodate that. It may end up creating 10 threads, or if the runnables are **amazingly** short-lived, may be able to reuse some earlier ones by the time you get to the end of your `for` loop. (It seems unlikely, but it's a theoretical possibility.)

Answer (score 1):

The threads are started one after each other as the for loop is executed in only one thread (the main thread) that executes one statement at the time. It is just very fast, so you could think that it is executed at the same time.